# How to resize datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have a datagridview in winform and would like to do two things.  Resize the datagrid so that all columns are showen (no scrolls) based on the datagrid size resize the width of the winform.

- tried the code below but it doesn't work*

  ```
      int width = 0; 
      foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in information.Columns)
      {
          width += col.Width;
      }

      width += information.RowHeadersWidth;

      information.ClientSize = new Size(width + 100,height);
  ```

Comment: I added sample code to my answer which demonstrates that what I have told you works in a simple example.  If this helps you, please remember to upvote and accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple order of operations:

1. Set the AutoSizeColumnMode property of the DataGridView to AllCells.
2. Add the Width property of all the columns plus some slack for extra width from borders on the control, etc. (Maybe plus 2)
3. Set the Width property of the DataGridView to the width you calculated.
4. Set the form's Width to the Width of the DataGridView.

Up to you to actually code it.

**EDIT:  I am in front of a compiler now so I put this together:**

Go into Visual Studio.  Start a new Project.  Don't put anything onto the form in the designer.  Simply use this code in the initializer.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Create a DataGridView with 5 Columns
    // Each column is going to sized at 100 pixels wide which is default
    // Once filled, we will resize the form to fit the control
    DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
    }
    dataGridView1.Location = new Point(0, 0);

    // Add the DataGridView to the form
    this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);

    // Step 2:
    // Figure out the width of the DataGridView columns
    int width = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        width += col.Width;
    width += dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth;

    // Step 3:
    // Change the width of the DataGridView to match the column widths
    // I add 2 pixels to account for the control's borders
    dataGridView1.Width = width + 2;

    // Step 4:
    // Now make the form's width equal to the conbtrol's width
    // I add 16 to account for the form's boarders
    this.Width = dataGridView1.Width + 16;
}
```

This code creates a `DataGridView` with five columns and then sizes the control and the form exactly as you requested.  I followed the exact steps I outlined above (except for step 1 because I don't have any data in my columns).

This code works.  So if yours is NOT working, there must be something else silly that you have going on and I can't help you.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response but i did this and it still doesn't display all the columns    int width = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in information.Columns)
            {
                width += col.Width;
            }
            width += information.RowHeadersWidth;

            information.ClientSize = new Size(width + 100, height +100);

Comment: it still doesn't work.  The columns are created at runtime is that an issue

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What happens? Does the size not change? Have you set any break points? Are you sure the width variable is the right width before you try changing the control size? I need more information other than "it doesn't work". Sorry

Comment: Sorry ive been at it for about a half hr. Anyway the size changes from 756 to 846 however two columns are still not shown.

Comment: By any chance do you have a MaximumSize identified for the DataGridView? That could prevent you from sizing it as large as you need. Another thought is after you set the AutoSizeColumnMode, force the DataGridView to redraw itself. Could be a chance that when you get the width of the columns, they have not been resized yet. Aside from that, the steps I outlined should be adequate to do what you are looking for. I suspect you have something else odd going on. I apologize I can't be of more help tonight - I'm in a smart phone and don't have a compiler in front of me.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I found out how to get this working using the following code below.  information is the datagrid and this is the form.

```
       int width = 0;

        this.information.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < information.Columns.Count; i++)
            width += information.Columns[i].GetPreferredWidth(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells, true);

        int rows = 0;

        this.information.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < information.Rows.Count; i++)
            rows += information.Rows[i].GetPreferredHeight(i, DataGridViewAutoSizeRowMode.AllCells, true);


        information.Size = new Size(width +20, rows+50);
        this.Width = width + 50;
```